# Razor view's directives list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, directive

```
@using
@model
```

What else directives can be used at the top of a Razor view? In `.aspx` views, we have tens of directives that we can use at the top of our view, and since Razor is something new, many articles on the Internet about ASP.NET MVC talk in `.aspx` language and some of them use directives. For example in [this](http://www.thegecko.org/index.php/2010/06/pluggable-mvc-2-0-using-mef-and-strongly-typed-views/) article, an `Assembly` directive is required to make it work. I solved that issue, but after some amount of search, couldn't find out a list of possible directives in Razor views, with their explanation.

Does such a list exist? Or am I still thinking the old way and missing something about Razor and `@using` and `@model` are the only directives we have in Razor views?

Comment: I believe those are the only two directives that exist in razor views.

Comment: Can we at least make a reference to it? Can we explain why we've lost other directives? Can we provide alternatives to them here?

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya Sooo is the answer then that `@model`, `@using` and `@inherits` are the only 3 directives Razor uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@inherits MyViewPage<IndexModel>
```

`MyViewPage` should be derived from `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>`

Comment: @gdoron : but with '@model' we can't inherit custom base class of view.